# mailto and literal control together

Tags: asp.net, literals, mailto

Is it possible to do this and how?

```
email: <a href="" mailto:""email1""">
         <asp:Literal ID="email1" runat="server" >
         </asp:Literal>
       </a> <br />
```

I try this but when I open outlook it doesn't write anything in TO: section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running under .net 3.5;

```
email:<a href="mailto:<%= Server.HtmlEncode(email1.Text) %>"><asp:Literal Text="info@example.com" ID="Literal1" runat="server"/></a><br/>
```

If your application is running under .net 4;

```
email:<a href="mailto:<%: email1.Text%>"><asp:Literal ID="email1" Text="info@example.com" runat="server"/></a><br/>
```

**NOTE:**
*although you can use the first approach on .net 4 as well, it's better to use the second one in order to avoid so called **syntactic noise***

hope this helps.